# A linear map $S$ so that $ST=TS$ and $ST^{n+1}=T^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Can anyone give me hints on this problem? I am currently very stuck.

Given a linear map $T:X \to X$ ($\dim X = n$) show that there is a map $S$ so that $ST = TS$ and $ST^{n+1} = T^n$

I noticed that if $T$ is invertible, then $S = T^{-1}$. The questions before this are relations with $T^n$, such as $N_{T^n} \bigoplus R_{T^n} = X$ and also $N_{T^{n+1}} = N_{T^n}$, and   $R_{T^{n+1}} = R_{T^n}$.

$N_T$ denotes the null space of $T$ and $R_T$ denotes the range.

Comment: If $T$ is nilpotent, then $S$ can be the identity

Comment: $ST^{N+1} = ST^{N+1}$? Is that a typo?

Comment: Where did they say that?@Algebrology

Comment: @FShrike in the title. I've submitted an edit.

Comment: Ah I didn’t even read the title that closely (I’m on the phone so it doesn’t format titles)

Comment: yeah, sorry for the typo, it's fixed now

Comment: What is the base field of the linear space $X$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net it's over an arbitrary field. Not necessarily $R$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea to think about the case of $T$ being invertible is very good and ideally leads to the general result. Note that the identity $(ST) T^n = T^n$ can somewhat be read as $S$ being the inverse of $T$ on $R_{T^n}$.

And indeed you can use $R_{T^n} = R_{T^{n+1}}$ to show that $T$ restricts to an invertible transformation on $R_{T^{n}}$. For this, it suffices to show that $T(R_{T^n}) = R_{T^{n}}$ because we are dealing with finite dimensional spaces, but it is also not difficult to use $N_{T^n} = N_{T^{n+1}}$ to show directly that the restriction of $T$ to $R_{T^n}$ is injective.

Thus you can define $S$ on $R_{T^n}$ to be the inverse of the restriction of $T$ onto that space. Extend $S$ to $X$ by $S(n) = 0$ for $n \in N_{T^n}$ (or by any other linear transformation, it does not matter) and you are done.

Comment: thank you for your answer!!